# How can I give different priorities to flask web-apps?

Tags: django, flask, gunicorn, thread-priority, nice

My Ubuntu server runs several applications built in Python (Django or Flask), and deployed using gunicorn. Some of them also use nginx. I would like to give some of these applications a higher priority, so that, if a prioritized application is used, its performance will not be hurt by non-prioritized applications used at the same time.

I know the Unix command `nice` could be used for giving different priorities to processes, but I do not know where exactly to apply this command: to the Python app? to the gunicorn command line? to nginx?